# Does Linux IPSEC support AH Transport with AES GMAC?

Tags: linux, cryptography, ipsec

Could not figure out if linux kernel 4.4 supports IPSEC AH transport with AES GMAC.

Trying various combination of "ip xfrm state" command but no luck. Is this implemented ?

```
Try 1 sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto ah spi 100 mode transport auth "rfc4106(gcm(aes))" 0x010203047aeaca3f87d060a12f4a4487d5a5c335 RTNETLINK answers: Function not implemented

Try 2 sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto ah spi 100 reqid 100 mode transport aead "rfc4543(gcm(aes))" 0x010203047aeaca3f87d060a12f4a4487d5a5c335 128 ALGO-TYPE values "enc", "aead", and "comp" are invalid with XFRM-PROTO value "ah"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code, it does support the algorithm under the cipher name rfc4543(gcm(aes)) for ESP, but I'm not sure if it does for AH. I guess technically this is considered an AEAD, meaning it is an encryption cipher (for ESP, not AH which is only authentication without encryption) even though it is NULL encryption.